# jquery UI autocomplete list from SQL Server query in cshtml

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, razor, autocomplete

I am following this jquery ui autocomplete template (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) but trying to pull my data for the autocomplete from a SQL Server db query.

It looks like when I get to my javascript I need my *availableTags* javascript array to have the form ["abc", "def", "ghi",..."] based on what is in the jquery ui demo source code.

```
var availableTags = [
   "ActionScript",
   "AppleScript",
   "Asp",
   "BASIC", 
   "..."];
```

My code currently gets me a list like this: abc, def, ghi,... . Actually I'm not even sure if it shows up as {abc, def, ghi,...} or [abc, def, ghi...] when I pass it to the javascript variable.

Here is my code to get the list from my db

```
@{
List<string> availableTags = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in db.Query("SELECT Tag FROM my_tags_table"))
   {
    var Tag = item.Tag ;
    availableTags.Add(Tag);
    string tagString = (string.Join(", ", availableTags.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
   }
  }
```

debugging shows that tagString is created as a list abc, def, ghi, ... but as I mentioned I need to add double quotes in there. Here is how I pass the tagString to a javascript array/variable.

```
 <script>
      $(function () {
      var availableTags = '<%=tagString%>';
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                 source: availableTags 
            });
      });
 </script>
```

Then here's my input box.

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="tags">
 </div>
```

Can someone help me 1) add the double quotes in and 2) do anything else that is required to availableTags to show up as a proper javascript array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery ui autocomplete needs the source property value as an array. `string.Join` method is going to return a string value separated by commas like
`Item1, Item2, Item3`.

What you need is an array.

```
@{
  List<string> availableTags = new List<string>();
  foreach (var item in db.Query("SELECT Tag FROM my_tags_table"))
  {
    var Tag = item.Tag ;
    availableTags.Add(Tag);       
  }
 }
```

and in your script section in the same view, you can convert this c# varibale (availableTags list) to a javascript array and use that.

```
$(function () {

    var availableTags = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                                                .SerializeObject(availableTags.ToArray()));
    $("#tags").autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, much less code and no need to try to explicitly build something that looks like an array with double quotes and square brackets and commas.